# Initialize ApplicationContext before loading WebApplicationInitializer Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Hi I am using the following class:

https://github.com/jarias/generator-jhipster-ember/blob/master/app/templates/src/main/java/package/config/_WebConfigurer.java

Note instead of implementing **ServletContextInitializer** I implement **WebApplicationInitializer** so that it is automatically bootstrapped and started by a Tomcat * server.

However I get the following errors in the logs:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Couldn't find a HealthCheckRegistry instance.
        at com.codahale.metrics.servlets.HealthCheckServlet.init(HealthCheckServlet.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4944)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

I believe the issue is due to applicationContext not been initialized before the overriden method :

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
 //   log.info("Web application configuration, using profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ASYNC);

    initMetrics(servletContext, disps);
    initUrlRewriteProductionFilter(servletContext, disps);
    initCachingHttpHeadersFilter(servletContext, disps);
    initGzipFilter(servletContext, disps);

    log.info("Web application fully configured");
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Show your public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) method?

Comment: Added. Basically exactly the same as the github link.